# STL containers' range insert functions returning void under c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, mingw, std

Just learning c++, so I may not be understanding this correctly, but I've only read that the range insert function returns an iterator under the new standard (C++ Primer 5th Ed, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/insert/), [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), and various answers suggesting to use it to maintain iterator validity).

From cppreference.com:

```
template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

However, every version of Cygwin GCC and MinGW that I've tried has returned void using -std=c++11. Even looking at the headers it would seem that that's how it's written, and that there's nothing I can modify to fix that.

What am I missing?

Here's the 'end of chapter exercise' function I was attempting to write; replacing one string with another within a given string:

(I understand it won't function as intended the way it's written)

```
void myfun(std::string& str, const std::string& oldStr, const std::string& newStr)
{
    auto cur = str.begin();
    while (cur != str.end())
    {
        auto temp = cur;
        auto oldCur = oldStr.begin();
        while (temp != str.end() && *oldCur == *temp)
        {
            ++oldCur;
            ++temp;
            if (oldCur == oldStr.end())
            {
                cur = str.erase(cur, temp);
                // Here we go. The problem spot!!!
                cur = str.insert(cur, newStr.begin(), newStr.end());
                break;
            }
        }
        ++cur;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which *version* of MinGW you're using? Please don't say *"every version"*. That doesn't help. Be specific.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The latest build using mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe, 4.6.2; i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.8.0-win32_rubenvb; x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.6.3-2-release-win64_rubenvb; and MinGW-TDM 4.7.1-dw2

Comment: Try. GCC `4.8.0`. It is the latest!

Comment: Seems like the standard library implementations haven't caught up to the new standard in some places.

Comment: @Nawaz: Even 4.8 doesn't implement it: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3dnNFJ$0 -- VC11 does though.

Comment: Note: this is less of a compiler issue and more of a Standard Library implementation issue. Whilst every compiler comes bundled with a Standard Library implementation, you may be able to swap an implementation for another: for example Clang compiles both libstdc++ and libc++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no compiler that fully supports `C++11` yet. Later versions of `gcc` and `clang` have a majority of the new standard implemented, but there are still parts that need to be done. Indeed, looking at `basic_string.h` for `gcc 4.7.0` shows that this version of `insert` has not yet been updated:

```
  template<class _InputIterator>
    void
    insert(iterator __p, _InputIterator __beg, _InputIterator __end) { ... }
```

Comment: If it's not just me botching things up, that eases some of the frustration, though I do wish that I could find a supported version. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Habnab: Visual Studio 11 has it properly implemented.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thank you. Though, I have been trying to avoid VS for some reason that is beyond me. Trying to stick to a minimal set of tools as I learn the language (vim and make/tup so far). I may just give in at some point. Much appreciate the help.

Comment: @Habnab: You can run the Visual Studio toolset from a command line, and even use makefiles with it, if you want.

Comment: I will most definitely try that, then! Thanks!