# list insert returns void for c++11, why?

Tags: gcc, c++11, insert, stdlist, gcc4.8

First a bit of background:

I've been writing for a programming assignment, which requires that I parse a text grammar file. In this, I need to replace a placeholder string in a `std::list<string>` with its corresponding expansion (the string represents a sentence).

I iterate through the list, and erase the matching string with:

```
itr = ls.erase(itr)
```

where itr is an iterator and ls is my `std::list<string>`

I then insert the expansion like

```
itr = ls.insert(itr, other.begin(), other.end());
```

where other is a container storing the expansion.

My problem is that the previous line apparently doesn't work. It's supposedly valid c++11 syntax, and I would really like for the iterator to point to the start of what I just inserted. But I get compile errors, as `insert` apparently returns `void`.

I've checked with cplusplus.com, and [as far as i can see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert), I don't see anything wrong with how I'm using it. [The standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (or at least the one that i can see) states:

```
iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first,
    InputIterator last);
```

I'm compiling using g++ (4.8.1) with the `-std=c++11` flag but when I look at stl_list.h in `(gcc-directory)/include/c++/4.8.1/bits` i see:

```
void
    insert(iterator __position, _InputIterator __first,_InputIterator __last)
```

Is this just because gcc hasn't fully implemented the c++11 library? Did they overlook this bit? Doesn't seem hard to do, and all the other insert functions surrounding it return an iterator.

I know I can work around this without too much hassle, but still it would be nice to know what's going on.

Thanks!

**edit** apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940603/stl-containers-range-insert-functions-returning-void-under-c11?rq=1) answers my question. Sorry to bother you, pity I couldn't find it before.

Comment: "*and the standard*" Nice though cppreference.com is, it is *not* "the standard". It's just a wiki.

Comment: ah ok, thanks, was a bit unsure on that. I'm pretty new to c++, the best i could find for free would be: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

Comment: I guess the libstdc++ version that is bundled with GCC 4.8 isn't updated in that regard yet.

Comment: @tang: The [C++11 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) has a direct link to the closest free thing to the C++11 standard: N3337.

Comment: @Xeo seems so. What I found was funny, is that all the other insert functions on a list return an iterator like they should. It was only the range insert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libstdc++ just hadn't been updated to return an iterator from that function yet.

That was fixed on the subversion trunk two months ago by this patch: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-07/msg00000.html

That change was made after the GCC 4.8.1 release, and I don't think the change has been backported to the 4.8 branch anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that might be the case but I wanted to check that it wasn't just a faulty or outdated library etc.